# Random walk converging to Brownian Motion for $t \in [0, \infty)$

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

If we define $X_i$ as a Bernoulli random variable with P(X=1) = P(X=-1) = 0.5. E[X_i] = 0, Var(X_i) = 1. As i have understood, by applying the Donsker's theorem,  $t \in [0, 1]$, $B_N(t) \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}} \sum_{i=0}^{Nt} X_i$ converges to the Wiener process in distribution as $N \rightarrow \infty$.  How can I extend t over $[0, \infty)$? Any hints are apprecitated

Comment: In which space exactly do you want convergence in distribution? The Skorohod space $D[0,\infty)$? In this case, which topology do you put on this space?